# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema

Tags: java, spring

Как только выпускаю jar и пытаюсь запустить вне Idea, вылазит ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
Offending resource: class path resource [spring/spring-app.xml]
```

Вот стартовый класс:
package ru.start;

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

@Configuration
public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/spring-app.xml");
//        ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) (ctx)).close();
    }
}
```

Вот spring-app.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <bean id="logger" scope="prototype" class="org.slf4j.LoggerFactory" factory-method="getLogger">
        <constructor-arg name="name" value="log" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.iiko"/>

    <task:annotation-driven executor="executor" scheduler="scheduler"/>
    <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="5"/>
    <task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10"/>
</beans>
```

Может я чего в pom.xml не подтянул?
Вот мои зависимости для spring:

```
<!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Помогите понять причину...

Comment: все мозги уже сломал...

Comment: если в Idea все запускается а в jar нет, то очевидно, что смотреть нужно в сторону корректной сборки jar. Откройте jar и проверьте все ли зависимости попали. Все ли зависимости и ресурсы присутствуют в classpath. Может быть и такое что в архиве могут быть и ресурсы и зависимости, но приложение их не видит потому что в classpath'e их нет

Comment: @МихаилРебров Вот это я понимаю, но знаний еще не хватает, чтоб разобраться. Готов оплатить консультацию.

Comment: я взглянул на Вашу проблему еще раз и сейчас убеждён в том что скорее всего мой прошлый комментарий был неточным. Я посмотрю  как будет время повнимательнее и напишу ответ.

Comment: по возможности приложите полностью pom.xml или хотя бы секцию `build`

Comment: @МихаилРебров  , я это пробовал, но у меня нет изменений в собираемом JAR. Видимо я где то не понимаю логику сборки проекта Идеей. Можем договориться, чтоб вы подключились по TeamViewer или AnyDesk и наглядно провели сборку проекта?

Comment: я то в целом не против, но боюсь что время на это будет уже только глубокой ночью. Днём времени и вечером у меня времени не так уж и много. Напишите в телеграмм @michaeldl...может и получится пересечься как нибудь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема, на мой взгляд, лежит в алгоритме сборки проекта Maven.

При сборке Maven извлекает содержимое всех зависимостей и кладёт их вкорень вперемешку с Вашими классами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такая же участь ждёт абсолютно всех ресурсов, включая и те что расположены в каталоге META-INF.
Тут то и кроется проблема.
Ибо Maven не "*мержит*" содержимое файлов , а просто перезаписывает их, в результате чего могут потеряться какие-либо данные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Вашем случае в трёх зависимостях спринга в каталоге META-INF лежат одноимённые файлы настроек.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в итоговый jar, по алгоритму maven, попадает только одна версия, т.к. при извлечении каждой последующей зависимости, одноименные файлы просто перезаписываются.

---

Полдела сделано - источник проблемы найден.
Осталось найти решение.

На английской версии SO в [аналогичной ситуации](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160534/how-to-create-spring-based-executable-jar-with-maven) предлагают использовать [onejar-maven-plugin](https://code.google.com/archive/p/onejar-maven-plugin/), который помогает правильно упаковать все зависимости без подобных коллизий.

Я же в свою очередь всегда использовал оригинальный **Spring Boot Maven Plugin** и не знал горя.

Добавьте плагин **spring-boot-maven-plugin** в секцию `build.plugins` pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!--   ...    -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!--   ...    -->
    </plugins>
</build>

<!--   при необходимости добавьте репозитории    -->
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

И пересоберите проект с помощью maven.

Spring Boot в данном случае заботливо сложит все зависимости в папочке lib в виде jar файлов, что поможет избежать коллизий и затёртых файликов настроек.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге мы имеем **ДО** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и **ПОСЛЕ** 
*(ошибок нет, таск в спринге выполняется)*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Доп.ссылки:**
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html
https://code.google.com/archive/p/onejar-maven-plugin/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160534/how-to-create-spring-based-executable-jar-with-maven

Comment: Михаил, я это пробовал, но у меня нет изменений в собираемом JAR. Видимо я где то не понимаю логику сборки проекта Идеей. Можем договориться, чтоб вы подключились по TeamViewer или AnyDesk и наглядно провели сборку проекта?